# Issue regarding Timestamp in ELK?

Tags: logging, logstash, kibana, elk, grok

I'm facing timestamp issue in ELK,

Right now what I'm facing issue with the @timestamp field of ELK that it shows the current date time while importing old log file.

I need to update @timestamp from custom datetime field from log.

Below is the sample log.

```
{​​​​​​​​ "datetime":"2021-08-24 04:13:39,167", "servername":"vm-ws", "serverip":"(null)", "process":"4656", "thread":"4", "level":"DEBUG", "appname":"AcManager", "page":"Program.cs ","method":"ExecuteAsync","line":"63","message":"Starting AcMa Module","otherinfo":{​​​​​​​​"token":"null","clientip":"null","clientbrowserversion":"null","clienttype":"null"}​​​​​​​​,"moreinfo":"null"}​​​​​​​​
```

I have used grok filter with below configuration in logstash

```
input {
    stdin {
        type => "stdin-type"
    }
    file {
        type => "json"
        path => [ "/home/testuser/mylogs/*.log", "/home/testuser/mylogs/*/*.log" ]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
        date {
                match => ["datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]
                target => ["@timestamp"]
        }

    # Step 1. Extract the JSON String, put it in a temporary field called "payload_raw"
    # Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => [ "%{JSON:payload_raw}" ]
        }
        pattern_definitions => {
            "JSON" => "{.*$"
        }
    }

    # Step 2. Parse the temporary "payload_raw" field, put the parsed data in a field called "payload"
    # Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

    json {
        source => "payload_raw"
        target => "payload"
    }
    
    # Step 3. Remove the temporary "payload_raw" field (and other fields)
    # Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html

    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "payload_raw","message" ]
    }

#   Tried this but not working
#   date {
#                match => [ "datetime", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
#                target => "@timestamp"
#        }

}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts  => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "datetime" field is present inside the "payload" field, you need to mention the field in this way :

```
date {
            match => [ "[payload][datetime]", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
            target => "@timestamp"
    }
```

This should be the right script :

```
    input {
    stdin {
        type => "stdin-type"
    }
    file {
        type => "json"
        path => [ "/home/testuser/mylogs/*.log", "/home/testuser/mylogs/*/*.log" ]
        start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {

    # Step 1. Extract the JSON String, put it in a temporary field called "payload_raw"
    # Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

    grok {
        match => {
            "message" => [ "%{JSON:payload_raw}" ]
        }
        pattern_definitions => {
            "JSON" => "{.*$"
        }
    }

    # Step 2. Parse the temporary "payload_raw" field, put the parsed data in a field called "payload"
    # Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html

    json {
        source => "payload_raw"
        target => "payload"
    }
    
    # Step 3. Remove the temporary "payload_raw" field (and other fields)
    # Docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html

    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "payload_raw","message" ]
    }

#   Try this
   date {
                match => [ "[payload][datetime]", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS" ]
                target => "@timestamp"
        }


}

output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
    elasticsearch {
        hosts  => "localhost:9200"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Swarna, we were trying payload.datetime.

Comment: if you want to preserve the current time i.e @timestamp you can save it in a separate field first. `mutate {rename => {"@timestamp" => "[event][created]"}}`
put this snippet as the first thing inside the `filter` block.